# PHP Curl, files, and 1-d/n-d post data not working

Tags: php, forms, apache, post, curl

I'm using curl in php to communicate between two servers.  We have it working properly for POST and multi-dimensional arrays, but it didn't work for files.  We got it working for files, but then it didn't work for multi-dimensional arrays.  The two ways are using,

```
$post = $_POST; 

//get files and include in data
foreach($_FILES as $name=>$info)
{
    if( strlen($info['tmp_name']) )
    {
        $post[$name] = "@{$info['tmp_name']};filename={$info['name']};type={$info['type']}";
    }
}

//$post = http_build_query( $_POST ); //works for multi-dimensional arrays (not files) and not doing this works for files and 1-d data

//use curl to pass information
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);                                                            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  //string vs array                                    

//test on recieving end
die(print_r($_POST, true) . print_r($_FILES,true));
```

Is there a way to handle both files and single/multi-dimensional post data?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the file in base64, this way it becomes a string instead of binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Ran a couple tests, and saw information on PHP website where someone commented on how it doesn't work for both (php,apache,curl).  There solution showed a specific example with hardcoded results to meet their needs, but I expanded the concept to be more generic and handle both single d, multi-d, and file data.

```
    //encode function found online for specific CURL use (on curl side)
    function _encode($arrays, &$new = array(), $prefix = null)
    {
        if ( is_object( $arrays ) )
        {
            $arrays = get_object_vars( $arrays );
        }

        foreach ( $arrays as $key => $value ) {
            $k = isset( $prefix ) ? $prefix . '[' . $key . ']' : $key;
            if ( is_array( $value ) OR is_object( $value )  ) {
                $this->_encode( $value, $new, $k );
            } else {
                $new[$k] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

//use on curl side
$post = $_POST; 

//get files and include in data
foreach($_FILES as $name=>$info)
{
    if( strlen($info['tmp_name']) )
    {
        $post[$name] = "@{$info['tmp_name']};filename={$info['name']};type={$info['type']}";
    }
}
```

//encode post generically to cover every use case (files, single d, multi-d, any form setup without hardcoding)
   $encoded = array();
   _encode( $post, $encoded );

//use curl to pass information
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  //pass as an array

```
//test on recieving end
die(print_r($_POST, true) . print_r($_FILES,true)); //everything as expected
```